# How do I return an array in a response

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to return an array in HTTP response. I'm thinking to return array as JSON objects. I'm doing `echo json_encode($arr)`  but I get nothing in the response.

**UPDATE:** I'm running a version of PHP that does not have json_encode method. json_encode was introduced in PHP 5.2.  So I guess question is how would you return an array without using json_encode?

```
     $arr = array();
    foreach($_POST['ids'] as $id)
    {
        $arr[$id] = $id;
    }   
    echo json_encode($arr);

    return;
```

Here are contents of my array:

```
array(18) {
  [156795]=>
  string(6) "156795"
  [156800]=>
  string(6) "156800"
  [4292]=>
  string(4) "4292"
  [796053]=>
  string(6) "796053"
  [660520]=>
  string(6) "660520"
 ...
```

Comment: Show us your actual code. We can't debug based on your short description.

Comment: JSON is definitely the right method. But nothing is wrong here. Show your javascript, and your full server-side method.

Comment: I updated question with more of my code.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to set the proper MIME type when sending back JSON:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

`json_encode()` requires PHP 5.2.0 or above. Make sure your host hasn't compiled PHP with the `--disable-json` flag. Both of these can be checked with the `phpinfo()` function. The code you've posted so far works fine for me.

Comment: Looks like this is it. I have PHP Version 5.1.4 running. What is the next best thing to do in order to return an array?

Comment: You could use a `json_encode()` alternative - e.g. http://www.mike-griffiths.co.uk/php-json_encode-alternative/

Comment: sorry i'm new to php but how would you return array before php 5.2? would you use something like serialize?

Answer (score 0):

json encode should do it with no problems.  When I pump that data into an array it works fine.  Can you post some code for building the array?  What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 0):

plz use json validator to make sure ur json is correct

look I did this & it worked fine

```
 $arr = array();
 $i=0;
    while($i<10)
    {
        $arr[$i] = $i;
        $i++;
    }   
    echo json_encode($arr);

    return;
```